# Allow broadcast traffic between VLANs in TPLink Omada SDN

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan, tp-link

I am managing a network with a few VLans, mostly ethernet connected.
Everything is controller through [TpLink Omada SDN](https://www.tp-link.com/us/omada-sdn/).

**It seems that there is no way to pass broadcast packets between VLANs in Omada SDN.**

The scenario is to send a [magic package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) from `VLan A` to `VLan B`.

The only way to make it work is set the network switch port of `VLan B` to be tagged for `VLan B` and untagged for `VLan A`, which is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Ethernet broadcasts cannot be forwarded between VLANs.

On the IP level (network layer), a *limited broadcast* to 255.255.255.255 cannot be forwarded either.

A *directed broadcast* to a subnet's broadcast address (with all host bits set to `1`, e.g. 192.168.1.255/24) *may* be forwarded/routed if the router (or L3 switch) is explicitly configured to do so. Usually, only the last-hop router is required to be configured as previous switches don't know it's a directed broadcast address.

If you don't want to or can't configure directed broadcast forwarding, there's a workaround: allocate a normal IP address in the same subnet as your WoL device and add a static ARP entry for that address on the last-hop router with a made up MAC address (for cleanliness, use an LAA address with the second least significant bit in the first octet set to 1). Then send the magic packet to that IP address. The made up MAC address is unknown to your switch(es), so the magic packet gets flooded to all ports, including the one with your WoL device on it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we came up with was based on the valuable help of Zac67.

We set up a tiny vm that joined the target VLAN with its sole purpose of sending WoL packages.